# Encode in windows container?

Tags: windows, docker, windows-container

I have an EXE program for file format conversion. The input file name sometimes contains Chinese or other characters, but I encountered some environment encoding issues during the docker deployment process. The program can run normally on `Windows 10/11`, where the language environment is `zh-CN` and the code page displayed by the `chcp` command is `936`.

The docker environment uses the image `mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022`, and the host environment is Windows 11 with the parameter --isolation=process. In the container, using `Get-WinSystemLocale` shows `zh-CN`, which is the same as the host. However, the `chcp` command still shows `437`, so I think it’s a code page issue. I’m not sure if this is correct.

I tried to run it on a newly installed Windows 10 with English language, but it failed. After setting Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative Language for non-Unicode programs to Chinese Simplified, it works.

**Update:** During my test on @GChuf 2 solutions, i found this may not be `chcp` problem. After change chcp to `936` sucessfully in docker, if `myprogram.exe` take Chinese characters as input, it can't output right content.

So, I simplified the problem a bit and wrote a `helloworld` test program. The program receives parameters that may contain Chinese characters and then prints out the parameters.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::cout << argv[1] << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In Windows host, `chcp:936`, `Get-WinSystemLocale:zh-CN`

```bash
.\helloworld.exe hello // hello
.\helloworld.exe 你好  // 你好
```

In docker, `chcp:936`, `Get-WinSystemLocale:zh-CN`

```bash
.\helloworld.exe hello // hello
.\helloworld.exe 你好  // ??
```

Comment: How to set in docker to make it work ?

Comment: Did you try to execute chcp command when building or deploying the docker container?

Comment: @GChuf Thanks for  your reply, just tried,  when building the docker container, it is 65001.

Comment: I wrote down 2 ideas as an answer - let me know if it helps

Comment: @GChuf ok, I will try later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following two helpful reference links. According to what was said above, using the following command on `my_program.exe` worked.

1. touch `my_program.1.mainfest` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    ...
    <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2019/WindowsSettings">
            <activeCodePage>Legacy</activeCodePage>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
    </asmv3:application>
    ...
</assembly>
```

2. In powershell, exec this command

```bash
mt.exe -manifest my_program.1.manifest -outputresource:.\my_program.exe;#1
```

3. Copy `my_program.exe` to docker container, and it work well.

Reference:

1. [Encoding inside container](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/336#issuecomment-1479960821)
2. [The activeCodePage manifest element can be used for more than just setting UTF-8 as the active code page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220531-00/?p=106697)
3. [code-page-identifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers)
4. [Installing Language Packs for Windows in containers](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/234)
5. [Publish Server Core image with da-DK culture](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Containers/issues/95)

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 solutions to this problem:

1. You can try to modify the global codepage setting when building your container - I'm not 100% sure where that setting is (it's inside the registry - chcp **does not** change global settings).
   Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8) for setting codepage for **console only**.
   You could try to find out which key is modified when you change "Control Panel -> Region -> Administrative Language for non-Unicode" by monitoring the registry, or ocmparing 2 versions of registry.
2. You can try to set chcp **BEFORE** you call your .exe file - because chcp only changes the codepage for the current session (if you open another cmd window, you will have to change the codepage again). In batch file, this would look like this: `chcp 936 && C:\your_program.exe $filepath` (you would have to pass the filepath as an argument to your batch file, which slightly complicates things. Maybe you can do something similar without a batch file as well.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have updated the question description, `chcp` seems not be the problem.

Comment: Ok, 2 questions - does the program still work if you manually change adninistrative language for non unicode programs inn control panel? And do you build the program inside or outside of the container?

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic reply. I have now found the cause and recorded the work I have done. I wrote an answer as reference. As for your two questions, 1. The program runs normally after the change. 2. The program was built outside the container.